# Cannot find element using Selenium find_element_by_partial_link_text

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I am attempting to click the "View More Results" button on the following page: http://www.chadbourne.com/search/people?az[b]=b

My code is straight forward, and I have tried a number of iterations.

```
driver = driver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.chadbourne.com/search/people?az[b]=b")
element = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("View more results")
```

or

```
element = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("view")
```

or

```
element = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("results")
```

No matter which of the above options I try, I get a NoSuchElementException.

This is odd, because the element clearly exists on the page:

```
<a href="/search/people?s=&amp;az[b]=b&amp;&amp;&amp;&amp;&amp;&amp;&amp;&amp;page=1">View more results</a>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It takes some time for the page to load, the element is not immediately available. Let's [wait for it](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) *to be clickable* and change the locator to a CSS selector:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.chadbourne.com/search/people?az[b]=b")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

# get more results
more_results = wait.until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".load-more-pager-wrapper .pager-next"))
)
more_results.click()
```

Comment: I just tried something else.  When I use all caps "VIEW MORE RESULTS", it seems to work even though the html indicates that the link text is not all caps.  Either way, thanks for your response.  What a weird problem this is.

Comment: @NeilAggarwal yeah, I think converting the link text to upper case should also work. Good point.